# C# extract words starting with : with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use C# to extract words such as the following from sentence.

Sample Sentence: Dog has :found$bone and :found$water

I tried using the following regex

```
@"(?<!\w):\w+", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

This only returns "found" in the Matches.  Why is it ignoring the $ and how do I fix it?

Comment: `$` is not a word character.

Comment: Is there a way to get the words found$bone and found$water to be returned by the matches

Comment: Something like `:([\w\$]+)`?

Comment: For what it's worth, a non-Regex method would be: `List<string> matches = sentence?.Split().Where(word => word.StartsWith(":") && word.Contains("$")).Select(word => word.Split('$')[1]).ToList();`

Comment: :([\w$]+) outputs found$bone, found, water the last match messes up

Comment: Just tested this one on [RegExr][1].

Seems to be doing exactly what you want, but I'm not sure if there will be any edge cases.


  [1]: http://regexr.com/3r98q

Comment: Use [`\B:(\S+)\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cB%3a%28%5cS%2b%29%5cb&i=Dog+has+%3afound%24bone+and+%3afound%24water)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex matches only the word characters and will not match the `$`.  Update the character class to include the `$` character with something like `[\w$]`.  Other aspects of your regex seem to be overcomplicating things, so a final regex could look like

```
\s:([\w$]+)
```

which looks for a whitespace followed by a colon followed by one or more characters that are word character or the `$` character.

Depending on what you're actually interested in capturing, you might use a regex like

```
\s:(\w+)$(\w+)
```

Example on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/44J333)